# precomputed matric cost much memory in dbscan in cluster

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-computing, dbscan

There are 40 million datasets in my scieniao.Can dbscan support so large datasets in sklean?Below is my code

```
result=[]
for line in open("./raw_data1"):
#for line in sys.stdin:
        tagid_result = [0]*10
        line = line.strip()
        fields = line.split("\t")
        if len(fields)<6:
                continue
        tagid = fields[3]
        tagids = tagid.split(":")
        for i in tagids:
                tagid_result[tagid2idx[i]] = 1
        result.append(tagid_result)

distance_matrix = pairwise_distances(X, metric='jaccard')
#print (distance_matrix)
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=0.1, min_samples=1200, metric="precomputed", n_jobs=-1)
db = dbscan.fit(distance_matrix)
for i in range(0,len(db.labels_)):
        print (db.labels_[i])
```

How can it improve my code to support large datasets?

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN itself never requires your data to be available as a matrix, and will only need linear memory.

Unfortunately for you, the sklearn authors decided to implement DBSCAN a bit **different than the original article**. This causes their implementation to potentially use much more memory. In cases such as yours, these decisions can have drawbacks.

For Jaccard distance, the neighborhood search of DBSCAN can be nicely accelerated for example with inverted indexes. But even so, you only need to compute one row at a time if you implement the "textbook" version of DBSCAN *yourself*.